# Can't get IIS Express and .Less Files to work

Tags: asp.net-core, mime-types, iis-express

I have inherited a .NET core project that uses .Less files but I cannot get it to run locally in IIS Express.

I followed this page to add .Less Mimemap to the global config
https://johandorper.com/log/add-less-to-iis-express
But now I am getting a 500 error, before I was getting a 404

The 500 error I am getting is:

[image: error]

I have also tried adding .less to the projects webconfig with no difference.

All the .less files are in the content folder of my project, do I need to do anything else to make them load (I have never used .less before)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, it's permissions.
I needed to run Visual Studio as an Administrator